# How to Get Sum of Specific Records and Sum of all Records in One Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I Have Table ( **emp** ):

[image: emp Table]

I want to get **First Column**

- **DeptNo**

Second Column

- **SUM of salaries of the employees of each department whose name start with 'A'**

and Third column

- **Total Salaries of all the employees of that department**

I am able to Get first and second Column but unable to get Thiird column with same Query:

```
SELECT DeptNo, SUM(Salary) AS 'Name Contains A', SUM(Salary) AS 'Total Salary'
FROM emp
WHERE Ename LIKE 'A%' 
GROUP BY DeptNo
```

Any Suggestions how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your DBMS supports `CASE`, you can do something like this:

```
select 
  deptno, 
  sum(case when ename like 'A%' then salary else 0 end) as ASalary,
  sum(salary) as AllSalaries
from 
  emp
group by 
  deptno
```

This produces

```
deptno  ASalary AllSalaries 
------  ------- -----------
10       300    500
12       100    100
14         0    500
15       400    700
```

Comment: Are rows grouped first and then other operations are performed? isnt that? can you explain a little bit

Comment: @Umair: It works like every other SQL statement. Use EXPLAIN in whatever DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT DeptNo, SUM(Salary) AS 'Name Contains A',
       (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM emp) AS 'Total Salary'
FROM emp
WHERE Ename LIKE 'A%'
GROUP BY DeptNo
```

Comment: it will not produce Desired result for Total salary  .. its calculating 1800 for all he departments

Comment: Missed the 'of that department' requirement for the 'total salary', for that solution with `CASE` is one to go

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, what you are asking is not possible with SQL, but you can get a sum of all the results in the query using the `WITH ROLLUP` clause as an additional row:

```
SELECT DeptNo, SUM(Salary)
FROM emp
WHERE Ename LIKE 'A%'
GROUP BY DeptNo WITH ROLLUP
```

This will give you a grouping of salaries by department and an extra row with a summing of all the salaries for matching departments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT emp."DeptNo", SUM(emp."Salary") AS "Name Contains A", sum("DeptTotals"."DeptTotal")
FROM emp inner join (select "DeptNo", sum("Salary") as "DeptTotal"
from emp
group by "DeptNo"
) as "DeptTotals" on "DeptTotals"."DeptNo" = emp."DeptNo"
WHERE emp."Ename" LIKE 'A%' 
GROUP BY emp."DeptNo"
```

So you join your original query with a subquery which holds the total of all employees of the same dept.